# cx_Freeze not including dbm

Tags: python

Does anyone have a setup.py file that would work for my program? My entire program is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/rockpaperscissorsv2-follow-up-advanced). Is there anyway to import one of the dbm's? 
I have tried many things to make my exe work. This is just the last one I have tried.

This is the setup.py file I used to turn my program into an exe file.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = []
for dbmodule in ['dbhash', 'gdbm', 'dbm', 'dumbdbm', 'gnu', 'ndbm', 'dumb',
                 'dbm.gnu', 'dbm.ndbm', 'dbm.dumb', 'gnudbm', 'ndbmdbm']:
    try:
        __import__(dbmodule)
    except ImportError:
        pass
    else:
        # If we found the module, ensure it's copied to the build directory.
        packages.append(dbmodule)
build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os','sys','shelve']}
setup(name='RockPaperScissors-V2',
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      version='0.1',
      description='Classic game of Rock Paper Scissors',
      executables = [Executable("RockPaperScissorsV2.py")])
```

I get this error when trying to run my exe program.

```
E:\Python3 Files\RockPaperScissors\build\exe.win32-3.4>RockPaperScissorsV2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "RockPaperScissorsV2.py", line 201, in <module>
  File "RockPaperScissorsV2.py", line 153, in start_game
  File "RockPaperScissorsV2.py", line 120, in intro
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\dbm\__init__.py", line 75, in open
    raise ImportError("no dbm clone found; tried %s" % _names)
ImportError: no dbm clone found; tried ['dbm.gnu', 'dbm.ndbm', 'dbm.dumb']
```

Comment: you can also try http://www.pyinstaller.org/ for freezing your code.

Comment: @anon Thanks I'll try it out. Do you have any idea what a dbm does??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after many tests I have found the answer. It was pretty simple actually. All I had to do was add `dbm` to the packages in the convert file.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['dbm']}
setup(name='RockPaperScissors-V2',
      version='0.1',
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      description='Classic game of Rock Paper Scissors',
      executables = [Executable("RockPaperScissorsV2.py")])
```